# Angular JS view hasn't been updated properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, apply, digest

I have found an issue in AngularJS which relates to wrong update of view. It occurs from time to time. The problem is when model gets a new value, view is not updated by new model value, but old value is appended by new model value.

While troubleshooting I checked that model contains a correct value.

Here is a view.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-repeat="p in point" id="{{'point-' + p.Id}}" class="{{p.BackgroundClass}}">
            <div class="point-number">{{p.Id}}</div>
            <div class="{{p.ImageClass}}"></div>           
            <div class="point-amount">{{p.Amount}}</div>
            <div class="point-quantity">{{p.Quantity}}</div>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller code which contains SignalR events processing:

```js
wetApiHubProxy.on('updatePointState', function (pointId, backgroundClassProp, imageClassProp) {
            pointsService.getPointById(pointId).then(function (point) {
                point.BackgroundClass = backgroundClassProp;
                console.log('imageClassProp ' + point.ImageClass);                    
                point.ImageClass = imageClassProp;
            });
        });
```

p.ImageClass is changing quite often. Changes/updates of view work in a correct way until sometimes occurs concatenation of old and new value.

Old p.ImageClass value is "point-state-configure".
New p.ImageClass value is "pump-state-off".

As a wrong result I have, where ImageClass contains concatenated values:

```html
   <div ng-repeat="p in points" id="point-4" class="point point-off" role="button" tabindex="0" style="">
            <div class="point-number ng-binding">4</div>
            <div class="point-state-configure pump-state-off" style=""></div>           
            <div class="point-amount ng-binding">926.93</div>
            <div class="point-quantity ng-binding">417.35 L</div>
        </div>
```

I have tried to call $scope.$apply() and $evalAsync, but that was hopeless. The strangest thing that issue occurs spontaneously. The only constant condition it's when $rootscope contains bigger amount of child scopes. Can anyone tell what place to dig and how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: It may work better if you use ng-class="p.ImageClass" instead of class="{p.ImageClass}".  Could you post more of your controller code?

Comment: I've tried with ng-class="p.ImageClass" , it doesn't help. Controller code is updated. Everything is good on server side, problem occurs on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` attribute is not intended to be used this way. You should use the `ng-class` directive instead.

I've created an example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/coldcue/o7q6gfs4/

JavaScript

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller("TestController", function($scope) {
    // Initialize the value
    $scope.state = "state-blue";

    // Change class on click
    $scope.click = function() {
      $scope.state = ($scope.state === "state-blue") ? "state-red" : "state-blue";
    }
  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-class="state">
    Some label
  </div>
  <input type="button" ng-click="click()" value="Click me">
</div>
```

But there are many more ways to use `ng-class`, read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass